# How to show that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in $[a, b]$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Assume that $a \lt b$ and that the continuous function
${\rm f} : \left[a, b\right] \to {\mathbb R}$ has the following two properties:
$\quad\left(\rm a\right)~{\rm f}\left(x\right) \geq 0\,,
\forall\ x \in \left[a, b\right]\quad$
and $\quad\left(\rm b\right)~\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{b}{\rm f}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x = 0}$.

How do I show that ${\rm f}\left(x\right) = 0\,, \forall\ x \in \left[a, b\right]\ {\large\rm }$?

Comment: Millionthplicate.

Answer (score 4):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Assume that $f(c) > 0$ for some point $c$. Then continuity implies that $f(x)  > 0$ in a small interval around $c$, and with this you should be able to derive a contradiction.

Comment: No contradiction, contraposition.